# The difference between signed and unsigned, what means a negative byte?

Tags: assembly, x86, unsigned, x86-16, signed

I need to solve the problem below, but I don't understand the concepts needed for solution.

Let's consider the following string of doublewords: B234**A68C**h, **52B4**78C8h, **1AB3**C470h, F9DC**98B6**h. It is required to:

1) print on the screen the *words*' ranks that have the *minimum* value from each doubleword (considering them *unsigned*)

The answer is '2112' (the bold words have the minimum value)

2) print on the screen the sum of the *bytes* that have the *maximum* value from these words (considering them *signed*)

3) print on the screen the *strictly negative* *lower words* of the doublewords

How can I differentiate signed from unsigned? What does actually mean negative lower word? Is it a value that doesn't fit in the interval [0, 255]?

Comment: A word on x86 is 16 bits. A negative word is one where bit 15 is set.

Comment: Do I need to convert the word in base 2 and check if bit 15 is 1 (so that the word is negative)?

Comment: `if(value & 0x8000) negative = true;` or in assembly `and ax, 0x8000; jne Negativ`

Comment: Or even `test ax,ax` / `js Negative`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **word** is 16 bits. A **doubleword** is 32 bits and can be thought of as made up of two individual words.

In a doubleword, the **lower word** is the low-order word (the one at the lower memory address, since x86 is little-endian). The **upper word** is the high-order word (the one at the higher memory address).

Registers don't differentiate between *signed* or *unsigned* values. There aren't two separate data types as you would normally think of them in a higher-level language. The difference between signed and unsigned only comes into play when you operate on words/doublewords using instructions. There are three classes of instructions:

- **Unsigned** instructions, which treat values in registers/memory as unsigned values. Example: `ja` (jump if above).
- **Signed** instructions, which treat values in registers/memory as signed values. Example: `jg` (jump if greater than).
- **Agnostic** instructions, which behave in such a way that it doesn't matter whether the values are interpreted as signed or unsigned. Example: `add` (signed and unsigned addition are the same since this is a property of two's-complement arithmetic).

Any reference page/document of x86 instructions should specify whether an instruction is signed or unsigned. If it doesn't specify, the instruction is agnostic.

Hope this helps clarify things a bit!

Comment: This is great insight, thank you! So basically, all I have to do is to use the correct set of instructions: `cmp dx, ax`, `ja`, respectively `cmp al, ah` or `cmp dl, dh`, `jl`

Comment: Isn't the size of a word relative to the processor you're working with?

Comment: @Nahiyan The question is tagged x86 and the answer is x86-specific. You're right, "word" can be used to mean a processor's native data/instruction unit size. In the x86 world though it means 16 bits.

Comment: Oh, my bad. This question is indeed tagged as x86-16. Thank you for the clarification!